# Changing default chart axis thickness in Billboard.js / D3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, less

I've created a chart with **Billboard.js** *(an interface chart library based on D3 v4+)*.
The problem I have is with the thickness of the axis which are made by default pretty thick, I couldn't find any method to make them slimmer.

This is how my chart looks like:

[image]

I managed to change their thickness when I right-clicked on them and opened in inspect, the element for the vertical axis is:

`<path class="domain" d="M-6,1H0V446H-6"></path>`

and for the horizontal axis it is:

`<path class="domain" d="M0,6V0H898V6"></path>`

I discovered that if I change the `6`s with `2`s in inspect mode to be like:

`<path class="domain" d="M-2,1H0V446H-2"></path>`  and

`<path class="domain" d="M0,2V0H898V2"></path>`, it will look much slimmer as it should be. Is there a way to make this change in the css/less file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is quite easy. Just set css rule for axis.
set rule for `.bb-axis` and set `stroke-width` property value you want.

Check out the example below.

```js
bb.generate({
 "data": {
  "columns": [
   ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150]
  ],
 }
});
```

```css
/* set for y axis */
.bb-axis.bb-axis-y path {
 stroke-width: 3px;
}

/* set for all the axes.
.bb-axis {
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
*/
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js@1.1.1/dist/billboard.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js@1.1.1/dist/billboard.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```