# Change the thickness of an axis in billboard.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, billboard.js

I tried to create a bar graph. The bars are fine but the thickness of the axis seems odd (too thick). It also creates a square gap on the axis junction. 
I tried to follow this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46886347/5122657)

```
/* does not work */
.bb-axis.bb-axis-y path {
    stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

to change the thickness but it does not work.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/h5c8df4n/

How to change the thickness of the axis?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplication of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705048/changing-default-chart-axis-thickness-in-billboard-js-d3-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already commented on github, but I'll be leaving for those who land on this.
Basically you need load a base CSS file for styling chart rendering.

Or without any css styling, add stroke and fill properties to style the thickness of the axis line.

```css
.bb-axis.bb-axis-y path {
    stroke-width: 3px;
    stroke: #000;
    fill: none;
}
```

Or checkout the working example with css file.
https://jsfiddle.net/goxbv8Le/2/